# Order of class definitions - any way to circumvent?

Tags: typescript

I am discovering that TypeScript does not give an error when I try to create a new instance of `class B` inside of `class A`.

```
class A {
    public static foo = new B();
}

class B { }
```

Calling `A.foo` after these definitions would obviously fail since B is not lexically before A. Removing `static` is not an option (because I do not want to).

So, is my only option to do the reordering of the class definitions manually, or are there any tricks I can do to circumvent this? Would a module loader help me here, or do I still need to explicitly define the depencency order?

Comment: I don't know any besides separating each class into an external module, in which case the ordering is ensured by the compiler. Every now and then I'll come up with a module that defines two classes (when some functionality unique to that module is needed), but in those cases I'll just manually ensure it's the correct ordering. Most of the times, module importing takes care of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Typescript code

```
class A {
    public static foo = new B();
}

class B { }
```

transpiles into following JavaScript:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.foo = new B();
    return A;
}());
var B = (function () {
    function B() {
    }
    return B;
}());
```

JavaScript processes file consequently, and at the line

```
    A.foo = new B();
```

"B" is undefined, because is not parsed by JS yet.

This can be solved via:

1) Reordering class declarations in the file

2) Extracting "B" class code into a separate file and referencing in in A file with

2.1) `/// <reference path="B.ts" />`

this should be added in the top of A.ts file,
this will explicitly define the dependency order

2.2) or using require (import) directive and modular building

#### Update 1

Variant 2.1:

a.ts

```
/// <reference path="b.ts" />
class A {
    public static foo = new B();
}
```

b.ts

```
export class B { }
```

Variant 2.2 (i've not tested exactly this code, but think it works):

a.ts

```
import { B } from "./b";

class A {
    public static foo = new B();
}

export { A };
```

b.ts

```
class B { }

export { B };
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide examples of 2.1 and 2.2?

Comment: Thanks. But really both approaches explicitly declare its dependencies anyway (through reference/import). I was hoping I could avoid writing these (as a I would if my original source code worked)

Comment: Unfortunately dependencies declaration is a headache of large TypeScript/JavaScript projects.